# How to convert Markdown files to Dokuwiki, on a PC

Tags: file-conversion, markdown, dokuwiki

I'm looking for a tool or script to convert [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) files to [Dokuwiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) format, that will run on a PC.

This is so that I can use [MarkdownPad](http://markdownpad.com/) on a PC to create initial drafts of documents, and then convert them to Dokuwiki format, to upload to a Dokuwiki installation that I have no control over. (This means that the [Markdown plugin](http://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:markdown) is no use to me.)

I *could* spend time writing a Python script to do the conversion myself, but I'd like to avoid spending time on this, if such a thing exists already.

The Markdown tags I'd like to have supported/converted are:

- Heading levels 1 - 5
- Bold, italic, underline, fixed width font
- Numbered and unnumbered lists
- Hyperlinks
- Horizontal rules

Does such a tool exist, or is there a good starting point available?

---

**Things I've found and considered**

- I initially thought that [txt2tags](http://txt2tags.org/) would be helpful, but although it can write both markdown and Dokuwiki, it is very tied to its own specific input format
- I've also seen [Markdown2Dokuwiki](https://gist.github.com/1869031), and although I'd certainly be willing to use a sed script, even on a PC, this only supports a tiny, tiny part of Markdown's syntax.
- [python-markdown2](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2) also sounded promising, but it only writes out HTML.
- [pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc) - but it [doesn't support Dokuwiki output](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/386)
- [MultiMarkdown](http://fletcher.github.com/peg-multimarkdown/) - [does not appear to support Dokuwiki output](https://github.com/fletcher/peg-multimarkdown/wiki/How-do-I-use-MultiMarkdown?)

Comment: Add filter to pandoc for DW output?! And, btw, for requested small subset you can **try** to start with pure Markdown in DW (did your read DW syntax rules?!)

Comment: @LazyBadger  Thanks. I just read http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/scripting.html, and as far as I can see, it is about changing the Pandoc AST. I want to keep the AST unchanged, but change the output format. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @LazyBadger Re your second suggestion, yes, I (believe I) know DW syntax very well! However, even if DW supported Markdown, I wish to convert the text to conventional DW syntax, for the sake of my colleagues who may edit it.

Comment: I've just discovered there is a very brief [Pandoc Issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/386) requesting DokuWiki support.

Comment: When I speak about pandoc integration, I have in mind "add additional writer", which, AFAICS, [doesn't change core](http://code.google.com/p/pandoc/issues/detail?id=170) as *MoinMoin reader* shows - it's just additional Haskell script

Comment: Ah right, adding a pandoc _writer_ definitely makes sense, once I knew what to Google for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an alternative approach I've been using recently.

Its advantages are:

- it converts a **much wider range of MarkDown syntax** than the Python script in [my other answer](https://superuser.com/a/407642/17574)
- it doesn't require python to be installed
- it doesn't require pandoc to be installed

The recipe:

1. Open the Markdown file in [**MarkdownPad 2**](http://markdownpad.com/)

   [image: MarkdownPad 2 Screenshot]
2. Select Edit -> "Copy Document as HTML"
3. Run [**Html2DokuWiki**](https://www.dokuwiki.org/tips:htmltowiki#html2dokuwiki_converter_gui_for_win32)

   [image: HTML to DokuWiki Screenshot]
4. Paste the HTML into the top "HTML Input" pane
5. Select All, and Copy all the text in the bottom "DokuWiki Output" pane

Answer (score 14):

### Stop-Press - August 2014

**Since [Pandoc 1.13](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/releases.html#pandoc-1.13-15-august-2014), Pandoc now contains my implementation of DokuWiki writing - and many more features are implemented there than in this script. So this script is now pretty-much redundant.**

---

Having originally said I didn't want to write a Python script to do the conversion, I ended up doing just that.

The real time-saving step was to use Pandoc to parse the Markdown text, and write out a JSON representation of the document. This JSON file was then mostly fairly easy to parse, and write out in DokuWiki format.

Below is the script, which implements the bits of Markdown and DokuWiki that I cared about - and a few more. (I've not uploaded the corresponding test suite that I wrote)

Requirements to use it:

- Python (I was using 2.7 on Windows)
- Pandoc installed, and pandoc.exe in your PATH (or edit the script to put in the full path to Pandoc instead)

I hope this saves someone else some time too...

**Edit 2**: 2013-06-26: I've now put this code into GitHub, at https://github.com/claremacrae/markdown_to_dokuwiki.py. Note that the code there adds support for more formats, and also contains a test suite.

**Edit 1**: adjusted to add code for parsing code samples in Markdown's backtick style:

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

import sys
import os
import json

__doc__ = """This script will read a text file in Markdown format,
and convert it to DokuWiki format.

The basic approach is to run pandoc to convert the markdown to JSON,
and then to parse the JSON output, and convert it to dokuwiki, which
is written to standard output

Requirements:
 - pandoc is in the user's PATH
"""

# TODOs
# underlined, fixed-width
# Code quotes

list_depth = 0
list_depth_increment = 2

def process_list( list_marker, value ):
    global list_depth
    list_depth += list_depth_increment
    result = ""
    for item in value:
        result += '\n' + list_depth * unicode( ' ' ) + list_marker + process_container( item )
    list_depth -= list_depth_increment
    if list_depth == 0:
        result += '\n'
    return result

def process_container( container ):
    if isinstance( container, dict ):
        assert( len(container) == 1 )
        key = container.keys()[ 0 ]
        value = container.values()[ 0 ]
        if key == 'Para':
            return process_container( value ) + '\n\n'
        if key == 'Str':
            return value
        elif key == 'Header':
            level = value[0]
            marker = ( 7 - level ) * unicode( '=' )
            return marker + unicode(' ') + process_container( value[1] ) + unicode(' ') + marker + unicode('\n\n')
        elif key == 'Strong':
            return unicode('**') + process_container( value ) + unicode('**')
        elif key == 'Emph':
            return unicode('//') + process_container( value ) + unicode('//')
        elif key == 'Code':
            return unicode("''") + value[1] + unicode("''")
        elif key == "Link":
            url = value[1][0]
            return unicode('[[') + url + unicode('|') + process_container( value[0] ) + unicode(']]')
        elif key == "BulletList":
            return process_list( unicode( '* ' ), value)
        elif key == "OrderedList":
            return process_list( unicode( '- ' ), value[1])
        elif key == "Plain":
            return process_container( value )
        elif key == "BlockQuote":
            # There is no representation of blockquotes in DokuWiki - we'll just
            # have to spit out the unmodified text
            return '\n' + process_container( value ) + '\n'

        #elif key == 'Code':
        #    return unicode("''") + process_container( value ) + unicode("''")
        else:
            return unicode("unknown map key: ") + key + unicode( " value: " ) + str( value )

    if isinstance( container, list ):
        result = unicode("")
        for value in container:
            result += process_container( value )
        return result

    if isinstance( container, unicode ):
        if container == unicode( "Space" ):
            return unicode( " " )
        elif container == unicode( "HorizontalRule" ):
            return unicode( "----\n\n" )

    return unicode("unknown") + str( container )

def process_pandoc_jason( data ):
    assert( len(data) == 2 )
    result = unicode('')
    for values in data[1]:
        result += process_container( values )
    print result

def convert_file( filename ):
    # Use pandoc to parse the input file, and write it out as json
    tempfile = "temp_script_output.json"
    command = "pandoc --to=json \"%s\" --output=%s" % ( filename, tempfile )
    #print command
    os.system( command )

    input_file = open(tempfile, 'r' )
    input_text = input_file.readline()
    input_file.close()

    ## Parse the data
    data = json.loads( input_text )
    process_pandoc_jason( data )

def main( files ):
    for filename in files:
        convert_file( filename )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    files = sys.argv[1:]

    if len( files ) == 0:
        sys.stderr.write( "Supply one or more filenames to convert on the command line\n" )
        return_code = 1
    else:
        main( files )
        return_code = 0

    sys.exit( return_code )
```

Comment: @OliverSalzburg You're welcome. (BTW, I just noticed a cosmetic typo: s/jason/json/ in several places... :-) )

Answer (score 2):

**Not ideal, but functional solution**

Markdown -> HTML -> Dokuwiki

First conversion done by pandoc

Second - [HTML-WikiConverter-DokuWiki](http://search.cpan.org/~diberri/HTML-WikiConverter-DokuWiki-0.53/) Perl module

**Hint: Reversing actions of existing code**

[silverstripe-doc-restructuring](https://github.com/chillu/silverstripe-doc-restructuring) git-repo contain code (PHP) for converting **from Dokuwiki to Markdown**

Comment: I tried this out, but, not being familiar with Perl, I didn't come close to getting the module to work.