# Creating a private wiki

Tags: windows, iphone, wiki, markdown

I want to create a simple, private wiki, but am really struggling to find what I need.  I require the following features:

- Private wiki.  Only I will read or write it.
- Some formatting capability: headings, bold, italic, bullets, block quotes
- **Wiki Viewer for Windows 7.**  If it comes with an editor, I need to be able to hide it.
- Page Editor for Windows 7.
- Page Editor for iPhone.
- Synchronize by cloud but available offline in Windows.

So far, my research has led me to [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) language.  I can easily edit this as plain text using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for Windows and [Elements](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/elements-dropbox-markdown/id382752422) for iPhone.  I can sync these files through [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) and have them available offline.  What I can't find is a suitable viewer for Windows.

I'd prefer to steer away from using HTML due to its verbose formatting codes.

Can anyone recommend a solution for me?  If need be, I'll happy to make a small one-off payment for software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [DokuWiki on a Stick](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki_on_a_stick) to set up a simple home wiki, and it was really easy to set up.

The DokuWiki syntax is much simpler than HTML. If you want to write in Markdown and convert to DokuWiki, I published a conversion script in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/407642/17574).

Although it probably doesn't support all your requirements (e.g. Synchronising by cloud), you might find it useful with some lateral thinking and experimenting, e.g. maybe trying putting it in Dropbox.

Comment: Looking interesting... I'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 1):

[Trunk Notes](http://www.appsonthemove.com/trunk.htm) meets some of your requirements:

- Private wiki. Only I will read or write it.

> Yes

- Some formatting capability: headings, bold, italic, bullets, block quotes

> Yes via markdown

- Wiki Viewer for Windows 7. If it comes with an editor, I need to be able to hide it.

> Not really, unless you count WiFi Sharing from your iPhone. Can't hide editor as far as I know.

- Page Editor for Windows 7

> Ditto

- Page Editor for iPhone

> Yes

- Synchronize by cloud but available offline in Windows

> Yes sync to Dropbox, not available offline in Windows

Trunk Notes developer is working on a Mac OS X desktop version. No Windows as far as I know.

Comment: As far as the iPhone editor goes, that could be better than *Elements*.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would give [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) a try. It's completely client-side "hosted", so incredibly portable. You can put it on a thumbdrive and take it with you anywhere, or put it in your Dropbox folder and access it from the cloud. All you need is a modern web browser.

It takes a little getting used to using a purely client-side browser application (mainly not having any page refreshes) and the app structure, but it's very handy as a personal wiki and has *minimal* setup. All you have to do is save the link to your computer and open it in your favorite browser.

Comment: TiddlwWiki is an impressive piece of work!  Unfortunately it's completely inappropriate for editing on an iPhone.  If it weren't for that, it would be perfect for my needs.